# Return matched value in any() list in string

Tags: python, string, match, any

I've the following script

```
#Tails every new line created in this file
for line in tailer.follow(open("my/path/chatlog.html")):
    #If the new line has the word "TURN" on it, continue
    if("TURN" in line):
        #IF any of the names in the list characterNames is in the new line, execute the function parseCharacter passing the matched "name"
        if any(name in line.lower() for name in characterNames):
            parseCharacter(charactersPath + name + ".xml")
```

That "name" in the last line is what I need to match the matched name in the line. I tried to check the any() documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `any` does not return the value that returned `True`. Use `next` instead.

Comment: [`any(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: What is tailer.follow?

Comment: tailer.follow is the method of the tailer package.

It checks every new line in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if any(name in line.lower() for name in characterNames):
    parseCharacter(charactersPath + name + ".xml")
```

To this:

```
try:
    bingo = next(name for name in characterNames if name in line.lower()):
except StopIteration:  # none found
    # break \ continue ?
else:
    parseCharacter(charactersPath + bingo + ".xml")
```

---

- `any()` goes though the iterator trying to find *any* value that returns `True` but does not tell you which one it was.
- `next()` will only return the *next* value that returns `True`. The catch here is that there might be multiple that do so. Do not use `next` if you want to get them **all**.

Finally, note that `next()` can also take a default argument in case nothing is found. You might wanna use that. If you do, you do not need the `except` part. It is handled internally.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if any(name in line.lower() for name in characterNames):
    parseCharacter(charactersPath + name + ".xml")
```

`name` is only valid in the brackets. Afterwards name is no longer defined.

You must go through the list manually:

```
for name in characterNames:
    if name in line.lower():
        parseCharacter(charactersPath + name + ".xml")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I guess I'll go with Ev. Kounis solution. I do prefer the try option with the next built-in funct.

Comment: @victorgonal: Good to know you like our solutions. Since you are new: Please vote for the solutions that helped you and accept the solution that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the any to a loop over a list from a list comprehension:

```
for name in [name for name in characterNames if name in line.lower()]:
    parseCharacter(charactersPath + name + ".xml")
```